# Automatic download of files from sharepoint with nodejs

Tags: node.js

I am new on javascript and I am trying to automate download of files from sharepoint with nodejs. The code is the following one:

```
const { sppull } = require("sppull");

const context = {
    siteUrl: "xxx",
    creds: {
        username: "xxx",
        password: "xxx"
    }
};

const options = {
    spRootFolder: "Shared%20Documents/SSC%20Projection/ZIP",
    dlRootFolder: "W:\\SCM\\RawData\\SSC_Proj"
};

sppull(context, options)
    .then((downloadResults) => {
        console.log("Files are downloaded");
        console.log("For more, please check the results", JSON.stringify(downloadResults));
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        console.log("Core error has happened", err);
    });
```

However,the engine is showing the following error message:

```
Folders proceeding: 0 out of 0 [recursive scanning...]
Error in getFolderContent: Cannot read property 'Folders' of undefined
Core error has happened Cannot read property 'Folders' of undefined

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: This error means that you are trying to access the property `Folders` of an object whose value is currently `undefined`. I don't see any `Folders` property. Where is the error fired (it should be in the error call stack) ? Can you please add the relevent code in your question ?

Comment: OK could you please correct code thaks

Comment: I can't. I don't know where your error is since I don't even see the relevent piece of code.

Comment: what is missing from the "not" relevant code I provided?

Comment: By relevent code, I mean the code that causes the error. The code you provided cannot throw this exact error. Somewhere you are trying to access the property `Folders`, but I don't know where.

Comment: When using `sppull`, please consider the `%20` in the url. I spend a day (!) on this problem when it got to me, that I should just have used a simple space bar `" "` instead. So in my case, it would be `Shared Documents/Contracts`. Even if I copy the url from SharePoint and get the `%20` inside the url, I need to replace them with a spacebar.